# как очистить удаление файли с деректорию /C:/Users/user/Downloads/

Tags: windows

как очистить удаление файли  с деректорию  /C:/Users/user/Downloads/. Может кто-то из вас знает как их от туда удалить

Comment: пожалуйста, используйте онлайн-переводчик с вашего родного языка на русский. например: https://translate.yandex.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите просто удалить всё в папке */Downloads*, тогда просто вводите эту команду в терминал (открыть терминал можно введя в поиск `cmd.exe`, искать нужно в меню Windows):

```
del /f /q "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\*.*"
```

Если же вы хотите восстановить файлы, то:

1. Все не полностью удалённые файлы находятся в корзине, их можно найти по такому пути:

```
%SYSTEMDRIVE%\$Recycle.Bin
```

Там же находятся скрытые папки корзины в которых лежат ваши файлы, или же через проводник, в левой его части можно нажать на "Корзина" и там будут также ваши не до конца удалённые файлы.

2. Если же вы удалили ваши файлы до конца, то тогда можно использовать утилиты по типу "Hetmen", "Undeleter", "Undelete 360" и другие подобные. Или же более легкий путь, но только если вы делали точку восстановления или ваша система её сама автоматически сделала.

- Заходите в меню Windows
- В поиске ищите: `Восстановление`
- Открываете его
- Далее нажимаете `Запустить восстановление` или типа такого.
- Следуйте инструкциям, если таковые имеются и просто ждите.
- Готово! Все данные сохранённые на той точке возвращены.